# EF 4.1 Commit changes stored in a dictionary

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am using EF 4.1 and in a certain point in my application, I read all the data satisfying a condition from an entity by performing:

```
context.Entity.Where(<condition>)
```

then, I iterate over them through a loop, and in specific situations I store some of them into a Dictionary (key value is the Id of the entity, and value is the entire object).

Later, in another point of my app, I read all the objects stored in the dictionary and I update them.

After updating them, I perform SaveChanges on the context, (the context is the same that was used when reading the entire entity and when items where stored in the dictionary.

So at this point, I would like to know if when I perform the savechanges, the data is sent to the database and udpated correctly since I am not sure as the objects modified come from the dictionary and I do not know if EF is so intelligent to know it should update database.

Comment: EF is tracking changes on your object, so they should be updated if only they were taken from the context. No matter where they were stored in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary as well as the EF context hold references to the objects. As long as the context isn't disposed, it will be able to track the changes.

In other words, putting your entities in a Dictionary (or List or  any other means of collection) has no influence on the entities and their context.